# How to make pip command use pyenv pip rather than default system pip?

Tags: python, macos, pip, virtualenv, pyenv

If I've used pyenv to change my Python version, I'd like to have the `pip` command be aware of this.

As is, it isn't.

Below, I've run `pyenv activate py-3.8.6`. I'm using Python 3.8.6.

```sh
(py-3.8.6) macbookpro13@Mys-MacBook-Pro ~ % which pip
/Users/macbookpro13/Library/Python/2.7/bin/pip
(py-3.8.6) macbookpro13@Mys-MacBook-Pro ~ % pyenv which pip
/Users/macbookpro13/.pyenv/versions/py-3.8.6/bin/pip
(py-3.8.6) macbookpro13@Mys-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

But the pip command still runs the default system pip, which means anything installed won't be available to pyenv's managed Python.

How to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by moving

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"

if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi


if which pyenv-virtualenv-init > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-in    it -)"; fi
```

.. lower in my `.zshrc` file. Something else was updating the pip path link.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced also this issue and managed to resolve by adding the following items to my `~/.zshrc`

```
export PATH=~/.pyenv/shims:$PATH
export PYENV_ROOT=$HOME/.pyenv
```

You can then check and confirm pip is loading from the pyenv shims

```
type python
python is /home/user/.pyenv/shims/python

type pip
pip is /home/user/.pyenv/shims/pip
```